# Access all case class values without reflection

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a case class and i have a scenario where i want to get all the field value of case class in string separated by - and if the value is not present for case class use empty string in that case.I am able to do it but using reflection, is there any other way of doing it without reflection?

```
case class Test(
               a: String,
               b: Int
               )


val test = Test( a = "aValue",
                 b = 1
               ) 

val result = test.getClass.getDeclaredFields
                .map { field =>
                  field.setAccessible(true)
                  Option(field.get(test)).getOrElse("")
                }
                .mkString("-")
```

aValue-1 would should be the result

Comment: What if you override toString method?

Comment: All case class implicitly implements ProductN trait. You can use productIterator to get an Iterator of all the fields. Alternatively, you can just override toString method which is more conventional.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`productIterator` method](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Product.html#productIterator:Iterator[Any]) all **case classes** have, followed with a `mkString`.

```
test.productIterator.map(v => Option(v).fold(ifEmpty = "")(_.toString)).mkString("-")
```

*(btw, this doesn't smell good, the possibility of a `null` on a **case class** is a bad practice, and this feels like a very rustic way to encode data)*.

Comment: In terms of speed, would it be better to use reflection?

Comment: @ScalaEnthusiastic **reflection** will always be slower, more unsafe and more insecure than any other alternative.